# mysqli_stmt::bind_param() not recognize new elelemt

Tags: php, mysqli

I send by a form the paramentres to this archive .php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bdpersona"); 

    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("insert into tbcontactos (nombre, edad, direccion) values (?, ?, ?) ");
    $sql->bind_param("sis", $nom, $edad, $dir);
    $nom = $_GET['nombre'];
    $edad = $_GET['edad'];
    $dir = $_GET['direccion'];
    $sql->execute();        
?>
```

So far, all is okey

I want a add new element "descuento". First, I add the element in the form same the the others and new column in database. Then:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bdpersona"); 

    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("insert into tbcontactos (nombre, edad, direccion, descuento) values (?, ?, ?, ?) ");
    $sql->bind_param("sis", $nom, $edad, $dir, $des);
    $nom = $_GET['nombre'];
    $edad = $_GET['edad'];
    $dir = $_GET['direccion'];
    $des = $_GET['descuento'];
    $sql->execute();        
?>
```

But I have a error:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\xampp\htdocs\fondomarino\insertar.php on line 8
```

What is the error???

Comment: the error is **Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables**

Comment: Look at your *types* string `$sql->bind_param("sis", $nom, $edad, $dir, $des);` It's "**sis**" yet you're binding **4** parameters.

Comment: `"sis",` -> `"siss"`

Comment: change bind_param to `$sql->bind_param("siss", $nom, $edad, $dir, $des);`

Comment: thank you!!!!!!!!! what difference there is between sis and siss??

Comment: thanks for the info!! :)